# How can I make something move in a specific order in a matrix?

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix

So I got this problem: I want to move from a black point to another like this:

[image]

but whenever I try to do it, it moves like this:

[image]

You can move only in 1 direction: north, south, east, and west at a time. 
I tried to do something like this:

```
        int distance = game.Distance(myPirate.Loc,loc);
        List<Direction> allDirections = new List<Direction>() { Direction.NORTH, Direction.SOUTH, Direction.WEST, Direction.EAST, Direction.NOTHING };
        Location destination;
        foreach (Direction dir in allDirections)
        {
            destination = game.Destination(myPirate, dir);
            int distance2 = game.Distance(destination, loc);
            if (distance2 < distance) return dir;
        }
        return Direction.NOTHING;
```

But whenever I try this code I get these results:

[image]

Can anyone help me figure out how to move like the 1st picture and not like the 2nd one? You get the location of the 2 black squares in the matrix.
If you need anything more, tell me.

Comment: Something like A* search with straight-line (Euclidean) distance as a heuristic function would probably apply?

Comment: @ap or if you look the other way [DDA line drawing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_differential_analyzer_%28graphics_algorithm%29) or other line-drawing algorithms.

Comment: I didnt understand how to use it, how can line drawing algoritem can help me here? :(

Answer (score 1):

As @ap and @AlexeiLevenkov already mentioned in their comments, you can use any line drawing algorithm to solve your task.

Consider your matrix as a pixel field (screen). You want to move from your start point to the end point in a shortest possible way, and that's of course a straight line (I'm sure you can remember that from your geometry course). So you have to "draw" a straight line between two points on a raster pixel field. That's exactly the point of those line drawing algorithms.

Let's use the simple DDA.

First, you have to determine your path line slope:

```
double slope = (endPoint.Y - startPoint.Y) / (double)(endPoint.X - startPoint.X);
```

Then you should look whether the slope absolute value is less or greater than 1. This is according to the algorithm. If it is less than or equal to 1, then we will move in horizontal direction on every step (so we're "sampling" with **dX = 1**). In the other case, we will move in vertical direction ("sampling" with **dY = 1**).

We have to prepare our "line": we calculate the **dX** and **dY** offsets according to the slope. For the case **dX == 1**, we will go left or right on each move and, additionally, calculate the next vertical "jump" using the **dY** value. If we determine that we should move up or down, we would normally do this additionally. But since there is only one move allowed on each iteration, we will need to skip our horizontal move and do a vertical instead.

In the next sample code, I will omit the **dY == 1** case. You can surely write it by yourself. Furthermore, this code is not that neat, but for the sake of simplicity I just leave it like that. You can optimize and refactor it.

```
private double dX, dY;
private double currentX, currentY;

void PrepareMoving(Point startPoint, Point endPoint)
{
    double slope = (endPoint.Y - startPoint.Y) / (double)(endPoint.X - startPoint.X);
    if (Math.Abs(slope) <= 1.0)
    {
        this.dX = Math.Sign(endPoint.X - startPoint.X);
        this.dY = slope;
    }
    else
    {
        this.dY = Math.Sign(endPoint.Y - startPoint.Y);
        this.dX = slope;
    }

    this.currentX = startPoint.X;
    this.currentY = startPoint.Y;
}

Direction DoNextMove(Point target)
{
    // If we already have reached the destination...
    if (new Point((int)this.currentX, (int)this.currentY) == target)
    {
        return Direction.NOTHING;
    }

    // if the horizontal moving is "primary"
    if (Math.Abs(this.dX) == 1.0)
    {       
        double nextValue = this.currentY + this.dY;
        try
        {
            // we have to move up or down if we've got a "jump"
            if (Math.Round(nextValue) != Math.Round(this.currentY))
            {
                return this.dY > 0 ? Direction.SOUTH : Direction.NORTH;
            }
            // otherwise, just perform the "normal" left or right move
            else
            {
                this.currentX += this.dX;
                return this.dX > 0 ? Direction.EAST : Direction.WEST;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // ensure we set the current values for the next move
            this.currentY = nextValue;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // You know what to do here: vertical moving is "primary"
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Random for dir in "(Direction dir in allDirections)", so that it checks different direction order every time and goes in zigzag way ..

Since it's always checking in the same direction order north>south>west>east>nothing it's going in straight line..

Comment: i cant do that, cant convert the direction to int